# How to import binance-java-api into an Android Studio project

Tags: java, maven, android-studio, gradle, binance

I have problems to import the [binance-java-api](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api) library into my android studio project.
I tried this :

```
implementation 'com.github.binance-exchange:binance-java-api:1.0.0'
```

Gradle sync seems to work but none of the lib import are recognized when I want to use them...

Edit : finally I have compiled the library, I think the maven repository hasn't been created. It's incredible that the Java api of a company like binance is so bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for now:

```
implementation group: 'com.github.binance-exchange', name: 'binance-java-api', version: 'master'
```

But as the last answer suggested, is better to do yourself the request and build your own interface.
That api, isn't official even the developer won the code challenger of Binance, the actual source code is broken in many ways.
I was trying to use it, and it has many bugs, which scares me a lot to use it in a Production environment.
Good luck with it!

Comment: Yeah I was shocked of the poor quality of this api client... Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually link it with this :

```
implementation 'com.github.binance-exchange:binance-java-api:1.0.0'
```

Or you need to create yourself the maven repository.
If you want to use the binance-api java client (which is not the best idea) you need to compile it using maven, and then link it in android studio !

But I suggest you to use the rest api wich is really better and create your own request.

Comment: Why is not best idea to use java binance official sdk?

Comment: Hi, the java binance official sdk seems to be made to support only future